# How to evaluate numbers in exponentional form using jeval?

Tags: java, math, evaluation

I have a problem evaluating expressions using [jeval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/) library that include values like 1.0E-4, or any other values with "-" after "E"

```
Evaluator mEvaluator = new Evaluator();
String r1 = mEvaluator.evaluate("1/10000"); // Works, r1 == "1.0E-4"
String r2 = mEvaluator.evaluate("1.0E-4");  // Doesn't work, exception is thrown
String r3 = mEvaluator.evaluate("1.0E4");   // Works, r3 == "1.0E4"
```

Exception is this:

```
12-25 12:10:51.495: W/System.err(5225): net.sourceforge.jeval.EvaluationException: Expression is invalid.
```

How can such values be evaluated using jeval?

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
String r2 = mEvaluator.evaluate("1/1.0E4");
```

Comment: didn't find anything in the javadocs or api, but it should work

Comment: the problem is, that this low exponential value is somewhere in the middle of the equation... More over, it can be returned during intermediate calculations... So, ideally I want to use the result of evaluate() in the next evaluate()... and it seems there will be needed check of what evaluated() had returned last time...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that jeval treats `1.0E-4` number as an expression with two operands: `1.0E` minus `4`. You can use some workaround, like cristi_b has advised. Another alternative is to use another scripting engine.

JDK 6 [provides API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) to evaluate JavaScript expressions, and I think they are compatible with what you try to eval:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval("1.0E-4");
```